# How to fade in images that are above the fold once they load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big image above the fold of my website that takes a few seconds to load, and once it loads it appears in a flash. Is there a way to capture this action with jQuery and make it fadeIn softly to make it feel a bit nicer on load?

Therefore, the real question is, onload, is there a way I can stop the image/s from loading with jQuery and then softly fade them in with fadeIn()?

Comment: If it's a jpg image, save it using `Progressive` instead of baseline.  This will sort of make it look as if it is fading in, instead of loading from top to bottom (baseline).  AFAIK, there is no way to control the way images load, but you can stop it from loading altogether, by placing it in a div with a style of `display: none` and than, either fading it in when the image is finished loading, or just show it.

Comment: I did think of that, but the main image will change and I might not be in control of the new image, which means I can't be sure it will be progressive every time. I was hoping for jQuery to be able to stop it form loading and then fading it in softly

Comment: Yes, you can place it in a hidden div until it is fully loaded and than you can fade it in, once the image is fully loaded.

Comment: Ah that sounds good, but how can jQuery know when it is loaded? That is my main confusion

Comment: `.load`, but it depends on how the images are being displayed on the page.  Did you say that the images are changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the images from loading, by placing it in a hidden div, and than you can show it when the page is loaded or when the image is loaded...

PLACING IMAGE in Hidden DIV Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $(".hidden").fadeIn();
});
```

DIRECTLY on IMAGE Example:

HTML:

```
<img class="hidden" src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hidden").load(function() { 
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```